# What is the difference between a ylide and a betaine?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm not sure what the exact difference between a ylide and a betaine is...

Are both zwitterions?

Something along the lines of: ALL ylides are betaines, but not all betains are ylides(according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betaine) the cation/anion group can be adjacent or nonadjacent)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The more definitive source for chemistry terminology is the IUPAC Gold Book.

[Betaine](http://goldbook.iupac.org/B00637.html)

> Originally, the compound betaine, $\ce{(CH3)3N+–CH2C(=O)O−}$ (*N*,*N*,*N*-trimethylammonioacetate), and similar zwitterionic compounds derived from other amino acids. By extension, neutral molecules having charge-separated forms with an onium atom which bears no hydrogen atoms and that is not adjacent to the anionic atom. Betaines cannot be represented without formal charges.

[Ylides](http://goldbook.iupac.org/Y06728.html)

> Compounds in which an anionic site $\ce{Y−}$ (originally on carbon, but now including other atoms) is attached directly to a heteroatom $\ce{X+}$ (usually nitrogen, phosphorus or sulfur) carrying a formal positive charge. They are thus 1,2-dipolar species of the type $\ce{R_mX+–Y−R_n}$.

So, ylides are not betaines and betaines are not ylides. Primarily due to the atoms in a ylide that contain the charges must be adjacent, and in betaines they must not be adjacent.

An example of a ylid would be the phosphonium ylid used in Wittig chemistry:

[image: Ylid]

Since it has adjacent positive and negative charges, it is classified as a ylid.

The addition of this ylid to a carbonyl compound would form a betaine *(note that the mechanism of the Wittig reaction is now thought to be a concerted [2+2] cycloaddition leading to the oxaphosphetane immediately, without the intermediacy of the betaine)*:

[image: Betaine]

Note that the ylid has an alternate resonance form (the one with a P=C double bond) which has no formal charges, whereas the betaine cannot be drawn without formal charges.

Comment: Quite nice answer. Welcome to Chemistry SE!

Comment: Great answer. It seems wiki has got it wrong.

Comment: @Nova Wiki is a great starting point, but not always technically correct.

Comment: You can format your posts using MathJaX: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here